# Why is this loop returning twice?

Tags: python, loops

I have the following code:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

f = open('AIDNIndustrySearchAll.txt', 'r')
g = open('AIDNurl.txt', 'w')
t = f.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(t)

list = []
counter = 0

for link in soup.find_all("a"):
    a = link.get('href')
    if re.search("V", a) != None:
        list.append(a)
        counter = counter + 1

new_list = ['http://www.aidn.org.au/{0}'.format(i) for i in list]
output = "\n".join(i for i in new_list)

g.write(output)

print output
print counter

f.close()
g.close()
```

It is basically going through a saved HTML page and pulling the links I am interested in. I am new to Python, so I am sure the code is terrible but it is (almost) working ;)

The current issue is that it is returning two copies of each link, not one. I am sure it has something to do with the way the loop is set up but am a bit stuck.

I welcome any help on this question (I can provide more details if required - such as HTML and more information on links I am looking for) as well as any general code improvements so I can learn as much as possible.

Comment: Are you sure that those links aren't duplicated in the input file?

Comment: Please post the HTML somewhere. It seems that the links occur twice.

Comment: (unrelated) `if re.search("V", a) != None` can be simplified to `if "V" in a`.

Comment: I would look at the HTML file and see whether there are multiple links. Also, add a simple `print repr(a)` after the `a=link.get` line to see what it finds.

Comment: And there is no need to use a generator expression in that `"\n".join()` call, just do `"\n".join(new_list)`.

Comment: Another unrelated improvement: `output = "\n".join(['http://www.aidn.org.au/{0}'.format(i) for i in list]`

Comment: And yet another unrelated improvement: the "counter" variable is not needed. Use ``len(list)`` for that. Also, don't name your variables like builtins, avoid ``list = []`` as it may even break stuff...

Comment: Offtopic: Don't use `list` as a variable name.

Comment: `the_hrefs = (link.get('href') for link in soup.find_all("a"))` and `the_list = [a for a in the_hrefs if 'V' in a]` would be even simpler.

Comment: Thanks so much for all the comments. Really helping me learn Python style and usage. Much appreciated. Turns out that each of the links was repeated in the html file so no issue fundamentally with the loop :) But the code is looking much better now with the suggestions. Loving how helpful this community is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have pointed out in comments, your loop looks OK so the repetition is likely to be in the HTML itself. If you can share a link to the HTML file perhaps we could be of more assistance.

As for general code improvements, here's how I might approach this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(open('AIDNIndustrySearchAll.txt', 'r'))

# create a generator that returns actual href entries
links = (x.get('href') for x in soup.find_all('a'))

# filter the links to only those that contain "V" and store it as a 
# set to remove duplicates
selected = set(a for a in links if "V" in a)

# build output string using selected links
output = "\n".join('http://www.aidn.org.au/{0}'.format(a) for a in selected)

# write the string to file
with open('AIDNurl.txt', 'w') as f:
  f.write(output)

print output
print len(selected)  # print number of selected links
```

Comment: Really tight code - thank you. Have marked this as the 'correct' answer as it helped most with the unrelated question I had with optimization. Turns out the html had multiple same hrefs so my bad there ;)

Comment: Quick question @ShawnChin how do I amend the code to only find the first link (to get around the code returning multiple links)? I tried links = (x.get('href') for x in soup.find('a')) but I get the error 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'get''. I thought soup.find was a valid method for finding only the first object? Thanks :)

Comment: `soup.find('a').get('href')` should be sufficient. `soup.find` returns an object not a list of objects so you can't iterate through it using `for x in ...`.

Comment: So @ShawnChin how would this integrate with the above code? Won't this just find one link from the entire html? How would I set up the iteration for this? Thanks

Comment: For anyone looking for a way to remove duplicates from a list try this `selected = list(set(selected))` in the context of the above code. Is fixing the issue after they have been parsed in, but still does the trick.

Comment: Question regarding `links = (x.get('href') for x in soup.find_all('a'))` - is this generating a list? I ask as it does not have [ ] which I thought was for creating a list. Is this some sort of generator that can be passed to a list? Just not 100% sure about what this object is in relation to a list. Perhaps someone could point me to the relevant part in the documentation? Thanks

Comment: Yes, `soup.find('a')` only returns the first match which I assumed was [what you wanted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13377070/why-is-this-loop-returning-twice/13378171#comment18274611_13378171). To get a list of ALL links with no duplications you can indeed use `set`. Try `selected = set(a for a in links if "V" in a)` to get a set of links (instead of a list). Sets can be iterated just as easy as lists. See updated answer.

Comment: The `(x for x in iterable)` construct is a [generator expression](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/). It's similar to list comprehension but produces a generator rather than a list, the advantage being that it does not need to store all results in memory and so is more efficient than building a temporary list.

Answer (score 2):

Since you've asked for code optimations too, I will post my suggestions as an answer. Feel free!

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

f = open('AIDNIndustrySearchAll.txt', 'r')
t = f.read()
f.close()

soup = BeautifulSoup(t)
results = []   ## 'list' is a built-in type and shouldn't be used as variable name

for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    a = link.get('href')
    if 'V' not in a:
        results.append(a)

formatted_results = ['http://www.aidn.org.au/{0}'.format(i) for i in results]
output = "\n".join(formatted_results)

g = open('AIDNurl.txt', 'w')
g.write(output)
g.close()

print output
print len(results)
```

This still doesn't fix your original problem, see my and other peoples question comments.

Answer (score 0):

Find_all returns a list of all elements. If you just want the first one you could do this:   `for link in soup.find_all("a")[:1]:` . It's not quite clear why the list is a copy of links. You can use print statements to get a better insight into the code. Print the list and the length of the list, etc. Or you can use [pdb](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html)